# Javafx exception when trying to copy fire

Tags: javafx, copy, fileutils

I've got a javafx application, what I'm trying to do is to copy one folder with a different name in the same folder if that makes sense. My application starts normally and I've got a set of buttons on my first stage/scene. I'm trying to get this to work by pressing one of the buttons. But I get an exception whichs seems to be related to the thread. I've no idea what the problem is though and how to approach it, from what I've read so far it could be a case of me trying to run this on the javafx main thread. Any ideas ?

```
  public void buttonTest(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        String usrdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(usrdir + "/.."+"/InteractiveGame");
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        String src = System.getProperty("user.dir" +"/.."+"/InteractiveGame");
        File srcDir = new File(src);
        String dest =System.getProperty("user.dir" +"/.."+"/NewGame");
        File destDir = new File(dest);
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
        }
```

The print method is to verify that I'm using the correct path's and I am.

This is the exception I get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
        at interactivefictiongame.pkg2.DBConnect.copyDir(DBConnect.java:63)
        at interactivefictiongame.pkg2.MainMenuController.buttonTest(MainMenuController.java:65)
        ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property

```
System.getProperty("user.dir" +"/.."+"/InteractiveGame")
```

so `src`, and similarly `dest`, are going to be `null`.

I suspect you mean

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/.."+"/InteractiveGame"
```

Comment: If you could see how hard I facepalmed myself just now ... you'd laugh out loud. Thank you James.